# Top level length of nested dictionaries of lists with one function

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a nested dictionary containing lists and need to get the total sum of the lengths of all the lists in each top-level value in the dictionary. An example list is the following:

```
data = {0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        1: {0: [11, 12],
            1: {0: [13, 14],
                1: [15, 16],
                2: [17, 18, 19, 20],
                3: {0: [43, 34],
                    1: [4],
                    2: [2, 3, 4, 5]}}}}
```

I believe I have a working solution using the following two functions:

```
def TreeSum(tree):
    return [len(v) if isinstance(v, list) else SubTreeSum(v) for v in tree.values()]

def SubTreeSum(tree):
    return sum([len(v) if isinstance(v, list) else SubTreeSum(v) for v in tree.values()])
```

The output of `TreeSum(data)` is `[10, 17]` and from `TreeSum(data[1][1])` it is `[2, 2, 4, 7]`.

I have tried to combine the functions into a single function, mainly for aesthetical reasons, but I have not figured out a solution. Can anybody suggest a solution to that problem?

Comment: I don't think there's a solution that's any more aesthetic than having two functions.  You could have a single function if you were doing a single thing (getting the total sum of the entire tree, i.e. what `SubTreeSum` does), but the top level is handled as a special case, so you either need two functions or you need one function that does two different things (by having an extra flag that gets flipped on the first recursive call or something like that -- which is a lot uglier than just having two functions IMO).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
def TreeSum(tree):
    return [len(v) if isinstance(v, list) else sum(TreeSum(v)) for v in tree.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate the case where you run the top-level function and the recursive calls:

```
def TreeSum(tree, agg=False):
    l =  [len(v) if isinstance(v, list) else TreeSum(v, True) for v in tree.values()]
    return sum(l) if agg else l
```

output:

```
>>> TreeSum(data)
[10, 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without passing behavior-changing flags is to just make `SubTreeSum` and nested function of `TreeSum`. Voila, single function:

```py
def TreeSum(tree):
    def SubTreeSum(tree):
        return sum([len(v) if isinstance(v, list) else SubTreeSum(v) for v in tree.values()])

    return [len(v) if isinstance(v, list) else SubTreeSum(v) for v in tree.values()]
```

Maybe prettier would be to strip out the common functionality into another nested function to avoid code duplication:

```py
def TreeSum(tree):
    def SubTreeList(tree):
        return [len(v) if isinstance(v, list) else SubTreeSum(v) for v in tree.values()]

    def SubTreeSum(tree):
        return sum(SubTreeList(tree))

    return SubTreeList(tree)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single recursive function by using the dictionary keys or list values as the iteration driver and counting 1 (for list items) or the recursive sum of the length list (for dictionaries):

```
def topCounts(C):
    return [1 if type(C) is list else sum(topCounts(C[k])) for k in C]
```

Output:

```
data = {0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        1: {0: [11, 12],
            1: {0: [13, 14],
                1: [15, 16],
                 2: [17, 18, 19, 20],
                 3: {0: [43, 34], 1: [4], 2: [2, 3, 4, 5]}}}}
    
print(topCounts(data))
print(topCounts(data[1][1]))

[10, 17]
[2, 2, 4, 7]
```